# Get compiled browser source code in java

Tags: java, javascript, html, web

Im trying to get web source code in the same format as I see it in google developer tools. The compiled source code, not the source code with javascript uncompiled.

Is there any easy way to get this code in java?

thanks

Comment: Javascript isn't compiled. What are you asking for?

Comment: please elaborate with some code snippet examples. Have no idea what you are asking for. ALso what is use case ?

Comment: javascript is a interpreted language

Comment: Ok, compile is not hte right word. I will try to explain - some javascript will create some DOM elements, and I want to see the HTML of all DOM element, even if in the source code there are none of them. In the source code is only javascript, Im not interested in the source code, but in the code that the javascript created. Is it more understandelbe now? I hope :)

Comment: you would need a headless browser to get the generated html

Comment: is there any for java?

Comment: can you google?  yes there are

Comment: ok, thanks. any experiences?

Comment: It looks like you are looking webdriver like selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is an interpreted language, there is no 'compiled' version to get. You might be talking about a minified version of a Javascript file. Javascript files are often 'minified' to reduce their download time. Minification is the removal of all unnecessary characters in the Javascript without changing the functionality.

Javascript and Java are not the same language, and if you're hoping to use Javascript code in Java that is not going to happen.

Comment: Take a look at [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) and [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html).